# Moving colspan from html to CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I've been looking around at tables and such and messing with them. Basically, I'm trying to have a `<th>` span across all 3 columns of the table. Now, I understand I can accomplish this by doing `<th colspan="3">`. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to move this over to the stylesheet. I found the `column-span` attribute, so I tried putting `<th class="span-all">` then in my stylesheet, I had:

```
.span-all {
    column-span: all;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for some reason. Is it not possible to accomplish this through CSS or am I going about it wrong?

Comment: what browser are you using it in? certain browsers wont work with that line alone.

Comment: `column-span` has nothing to do with `colspan` and will not replicate the same effect.  There is no CSS equivalent to `colspan` as it pertains to table structure.

Comment: that's unfortunate. Oh well... and I'm using Chrome version 60 something @schylake.

Comment: for that line of css to work on chrome it needs to be this  -webkit-column-span: all;

Comment: display:grid; can allow child to span rows and/or column if it set from css. Would you consider using display:grid ? You should share an HTML/CSS samples that shows your issue.see eventually: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ &    https://gridbyexample.com/examples/